# How to use RouterFunction of Spring in Jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

In simple project (spring-boot-starter-web) i just add
`(@Bean) RouterFunction ...`and it work for me

but in project generate by jhipster 7 i can't use RouterFunction , seem RouterFunction blocked by something.

i tried remove spring ,security ,webFilter,... .but still can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem :

the problem is that in ClientForwardController.forward() it blocked all Get request and (forward:/) before FunctionController.